# php - How to pass parameters to a function

Tags: php, parameters

I'm pretty sure this is a very basic question to all of you, but i'm new with php, and i don't really get it...
basically i've created a function in which i need to pass two parameters.

My functions is this:

```
function displayRoomDetails($customerRooms, $test)
{
    foreach ($customerRooms as $room) {
        $test.= $room->name;
    };
}
```

it is a very basic function, but will do for this example.

Now, i'm creating templates to display several information, and i have 3 different layout where i need to display the same info but styled differently, so my approach was:

```
template1 .= '<span>';

if (!$customerRooms == "") {
    displayRoomDetails($customerRooms,"template1");
};

template1 .= '</span>';
```

It should be pretty easy to understand, basically i'm calling the same functions in all the different templates passing as a parameter the template name and trying to append the results to the right template.

The problem i've got is this:
According to this example here ->
 http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_function3

i should be able to do this exactly like i did, but when i try, when i debug my function, $template doesn't take the passed value as i though it would, but it is still called `$test` and not `$template1...`

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The example you link to has practically nothing in common with your code at all.

Comment: Your code also immediately throws an error: *PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.=' (T_CONCAT_EQUAL) in - on line 2*

Comment: try `displayRoomDetails($customerRooms,$template1");`

Comment: its like you are calling "template1" within template1 and you want to display "template1".. if am not worng.

Comment: that if statement isn't doing what you think it is `if (!$customerRooms == "")`  the variable *is* being cast to boolean and inverted but the result is not being assigned to anything. You're still comparing `$customerRooms == ""` you probably need `if($customerRooms !== "")`

Comment: @andrew I think the `$customerRooms` is some kind of array/Iterable so it would be better to check the size of the collection instead of comparing it to an empty string (especially using `!==`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these changes:

```
function displayRoomDetails($customerRooms, &$test)
```

And

```
$template1 .= '<span>';
if ($customerRooms != "") {
  displayRoomDetails($customerRooms, $template1);
};
$template1 .= '</span>';
```

Comment: You should explain why you suggested using the `&`operator and what it does

Comment: Thanks! It's working. This is exactly what i needed.

Comment: Another copy-and-paste solution.

Comment: @andrew - yep, you are right. Nick - do you know what the & means?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to append some text to the `template1` variable using the `displayRoomDetailsFunction`

Some things to fix:

1. `template1` should be `$template1`
2. You should be passing the `$template1` not the `"template1"` (i.e. the variable itself not its name).
3. If you want to modify this variable you need to either:

   - pass it as [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php), which you can do by changing the function's declaration to: `function displayRoomDetails($customerRooms, &$test)`
   - return new string from function and assign it to the `$template1` by adding `return $test;` just after your `foreach` block and changing the call to `$template1 .= displayRoomDetails($customerRooms,$template1);`

Additional note: if `$customerRooms` is an array, it'd be better to check if it's not empty using `count()` than `!$customerRooms == ""`, see @andrew's comment for details